# VBA Progress bar based on CALL command scripts

Tags: vba, forms, call, progress

I have looked on the web, and find many nice guides on how to make progress bars using UserForms or the status bar of Excel, but common for all of these seems to be that they get the info from code in the form of formulas, not so much from scripts.

So basically i want a progress bar like this:

https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/beautiful-vba-progress-bar-with-step-by-step-instructions/

But which updates based on each call command from the script below.

I cannot figure out how to make it update just buy checking for the calls..

````
Sub ParentPath_By_NAME_Run()

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt

Call RUN_LOGIN_SAVE_TO_FILE 'Macro29
        
Call ParentPath_PF_Export_NAME 'Macro64
    
Call ParentPath_Comma_Remove 'Macro66
    
Call ParentPath_By_NAME 'Macro77
    
Call ParentPath_FullpathGET  'Macro117
    
Call ParentPath_Import_To_Excel 'Macro63
    
Call PFPerm_21_DELETE_LOGIN_FILES 'Macro28
    
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch").Range("C33"))
   
MsgBox "All Done!"
End Sub```

Can someone please help me? 

:)

Thanks.
````

Comment: What do you mean checking for calls? `ParentPath_By_NAME_Run` Knows when the calls are being run and when they are finished. 
So let `ParentPath_By_NAME_Run` update the progress bar between each call?

Comment: how do i do that then?

Comment: You cannot "check for calls" in any kind of generic sense  - you need to add some explicit updates *somewhere* in your code to update the progress bar.

Comment: Well, depends on exactly how your progress bar works. But in the tutorial that you refer to, if you go down to the "What if I don't have a loop?" Then the "'A portion of your macro goes here" parts of that code is where your calls would go, I'd imagine.